# Locking the screen in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lock the Android device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programmatically)

I want to lock the screen through my program. I am using the following code to do the same..But it's not working for me..I don't know where I am wrong..even I am not getting any errors in logcat..I am using 1.6

```
public class KeyGaurd extends Activity {
KeyguardManager keyguardManager;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     keyguardManager = 
        (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

        KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 

        lock.reenableKeyguard();
}
```

And I used the permission also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would lock the keyboard, not the device.  Try using the lockNow method in  [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html).

Comment: HI elevine...Is any other way to do this..?or can u share sample code using DevicePolicyManager.?I am new to android..Its some what difficult for me to understand at this point..